# What is using my external hard drive, without my permission, and how can I stop it?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, wd

I've noticed for a while now that my WD passport (2TB) blinks by itself, so I looked into the issue and checked in Resource Manager to see what's going on. In Resource Manager I saw that almost every program had its hand in my hard drive, including system. I found some solutions online including disabling my Recycle Bin, which I have done to no avail.

I'm afraid that long term reading and writing like this constantly could lead to a system failure, which would be devastating.

Could please explain to me what's going on? What are these programs (like Vivaldi) doing with my hard drive? Is this normal, and does it pose a risk to the longevity of my drive?

Most importantly, how do i stop it?  It makes safe ejection nearly impossible.

[image]

Comment: https://ibb.co/cNRp749
https://ibb.co/m5x4H45    here are some screenshots of the problem

Comment: What's on your F: drive?

Comment: please add the screenshots to the question ... they do not belong in a comment

Comment: In general, if you have something to add (clarification, answering a question...) please don't use comments, rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775049/edit) the original question. That keeps it up-to-date and everything relevant immediately available.

Comment: Most likely, 1. Windows drive scans fro malware. 2. Windows indexing drive for Search. 3. Application storing data.